# What Is The Purpose Of Asynchronous Servlet

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, asynchronous, servlet-3.0

I want to know the use of asynchronous servlet, is it possible to replace ajax with asynchronous servlet? if its possible then please guide me if not then what is the purpose of asynchronous servlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has built in support for server push etc.

For details see: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-2009/jw-02-servlet3.html

To quote the article:

> If the server could actively push data to browsers -- in other words, deliver asynchronous messages to clients on events (state changes) -- Ajax applications would perform better and save precious server and network resources

Comment: i got my answer from your link " If the server could actively push data to browsers -- in other words, deliver asynchronous messages to clients on events (state changes) -- Ajax applications would perform better and save precious server and network resources  "